# Zookeeper service discovery and Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

We are migrating from a monolithic application to microservices architectures.

Currently we have microservices (mostly spring boot) running on VM, which are used by the front with zookeeper service discovery.

I set up a docker swarm, and we'd like to migrate our microservices to docker containers, but we have to keep the front, and zookeeper cluster outside docker.
Thus when the microservices register (from docker container) on the zookeeper cluster, they use the ip of the container, which is not reachable from the front.

Is there another way to do that or have I to override the registration process of spring and make it register with one of the docker swarm ip ?

Comment: Have you tried launching your docker containers with `--net=host` option?

Comment: Is this option available with `docker service create ...` ?

Comment: It's an option for `docker run`, sorry. For `docker service create` try with `--network host`.
**docker service create --name <service_name> --network host <your_image> /bin/bash**

Comment: it registers as it should, the `--network host`do the trick, thank you